# prove that equation has only 1 solution

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, polynomials, cubics

> prove that the equation :
>   $4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx=a+b+c$
>   have only one solution.

what I did so far was to define $g(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2-(a+b+c)x$ so that $g(0)=0$ and also $g(1)=a+b+c-(a+b+c)=0$ so by Rolle's theorem
exist a point $d$ such that $g'(d)=0=4ad^3+3bd^2+2cd-a+b+c$. so $4ad^3+3bd^2+2cd=a+b+c$ but I have no idea how to prove that there isn't another solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong.

Try $a=c=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: your'e right, thank you.

Comment: good way to provide example, liked.